# Transformation of user-defined projected coordinatesystems

Tags: coordinate-system

I want to transform from one projected coordinate system (pcs) to another using ArcGIS 10. Unfortunatelly the starting system is not predefind by ESRI and thus I´m not sure the software is doing what I want. The parameter of the starting system are the the following:

Europe_Lambert_Conformal_Conic
Authority: Custom

Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting: 0,0
False_Northing: 0,0
Central_Meridian: 10,5
Standard_Parallel_1: 48,667
Standard_Parallel_2: 53,667
Latitude_Of_Origin: 51,0
Linear Unit: Meter (1,0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_WGS_1984
Angular Unit: Degree (0,0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0,0)
Datum: D_WGS_1984
  Spheroid: WGS_1984
    Semimajor Axis: 6378137,0
    Semiminor Axis: 6356752,314245179
    Inverse Flattening: 298,257223563

... and this should be transformed into: ETRS_1989_LAEA (WKID: 3035). What I have done is:
1. unprojecting to GCS WGS 1984
2. transformation to GCS ETRS 1989 (using the transformation option: ETRS_1989_To_WGS_1984)
3. projecting to ETRS_1989_LAEA

Now my question: does ArcGIS recognize the different userdefined standardparallels of the Lambert Conformal Conic projection as there is a predifined Lambert Conformal Conic projection already included in te software while unprojecting. The parameters of the predifined psc are the following:

Europe_Lambert_Conformal_Conic
WKID: 102014 Authority: ESRI

Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting: 0,0
False_Northing: 0,0
Central_Meridian: 10,0
Standard_Parallel_1: 43,0
Standard_Parallel_2: 62,0
Latitude_Of_Origin: 30,0
Linear Unit: Meter (1,0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_European_1950
Angular Unit: Degree (0,0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0,0)
Datum: D_European_1950
  Spheroid: International_1924
    Semimajor Axis: 6378388,0
    Semiminor Axis: 6356911,946127947
    Inverse Flattening: 297,0

As you may recognize I`m not not really sure what ArcGIS is doing in the transformation process of of one psc to another, in contrast the transformation from gsc to another gsc is understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workflow should have worked fine. In fact, you could perform the conversion as a single step using the Project Tool. The software will correctly piece together the different operations needed to convert from the source to the target coordinate reference systems.

Esri doesn't work on the coordinate reference system names.

You can confirm this by checking the results after your first step. If the definition was interpreted correctly, the data should overlay properly.